# 2 divs of different sizes centered

Tags: css

I am having an issue with div position. My website for reference is;

http://konzine.com

The issue I am having is tough to explain. I have a wrapper div of 1000px that is divided into two sections; one being 350px and the other being 650px. The wrapper is meant to be centered on the page, and have the left and right side correspond to that center. I would need the divs to stretch the width and length of the page to cover the sides in their corresponding color.

Is this possible?

Quick Edit;

I drew a picture to better illustrate my issue:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsRJG.jpg

The red line would represent the middle of the page, the entire black outline would be the wrapper div and the inner 2 separate colors are the 2 divs inside. I need them to maintain there center position on the page, but also be able to come out to fill the page.

Comment: So are the div's fixed width (350px and 650px) or do they need to stretch to fill the page? You can't have both obviously!

Comment: When you ask for CSS related help on the web, try to reproduce the issue using a small example code and post the example code. Don't expect everyone to go through the HTML and CSS of your website.

Comment: As I said I wasnt sure how to explain this correctly lol. Basically, I need the divs at a specific point on the users screen at all times. think of it as two 50% width divs, But I need them to move to the left of the 50% of the screen say 100px. Percents wont work because 60% and 40% on a large screen eventually gets off center. I havent really wrote any code because I wasnt sure if it was possible...

Answer (score 1):

Your reference site simply uses a centered background image repeated vertically which consists of the two colours.

In it's case the image is 3300px wide and so I had to stretch my browser over both monitors to see it's flaw. If you're ok with assuming that most people won't try and stretch it beyond the width of your image (technically you could make it as large as you like) then that might be the simplest way to do it.

The relevant css from the reference site is

```
html,body {
    background-image:url('images/background.gif');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

The rest of the site would just sit in the wrapper as normal.

Comment: If all he needs is the background then +1 for a very simple efficient solution!

Comment: ..I can't believe how easy and efficiently that worked. I really overlooked the simple things.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can horizontally-center the wrapper by settings its left and right margins to `auto`. For example, the following would horizontally center a `div` element with ID as `wrapper`.

```
div#wrapper {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

A complete example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
 PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        div#wrapper {
            width: 1000px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            overflow: hidden;
            border: 1px solid gray;
        }

        div#left {
            float: left;
            width: 50%;
            background: #bbccdd;
        }

        div#right {
            float: right;
            width: 50%;
            background: #ddeeff;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="left">
                foo<br />
                foo<br />
                foo<br />
                foo<br />
            </div>
            <div id="right">
                bar<br />
                bar<br />
                bar<br />
                bar<br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that when you use `float` in a `div` element, the containment of the container `div` breaks. That is fixed with `overflow: hidden`. This fix works for modern browsers. In case you want to fix this for IE6 as well, there is a clumsy fix which I've documented here: http://notes.susam.in/2011/06/float-containment.html